# Spotify docker-maven-plugin unauthorized: authentication required public repo

Tags: maven, docker, maven-plugin, spotify, docker-registry

I am having trouble pushing my docker image to the hub using the following command:

```
mvn clean package docker:build -DpushImage
```

Each time I get the following response:

```
[WARNING] Failed to push jdruwe/k8s-product-owner, retrying in 10 seconds (5/5).

...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default-cli) on project k8s-product-owner: Exception caught: unauthorized: authentication required -> [Help 1]
```

When I try to login using one of the following commands, I keep getting the errors even tough the login succeeded

```
docker login -u jdruwe https://index.docker.io/v1/

OR

docker login
```

I did create an empty repo on hub just to try fixing it:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you correctly configure the authentication settings?

User and password can be set in **settings.xml**:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>docker-hub</id>
    <username>jdruwe</username>
    <password>secret-password</password>
    <configuration>
      <email>foo@foo.bar</email>
    </configuration>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Then, the **pom** references these settings:

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION GOES HERE</version>
  <configuration>
    [...]
    <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
    <registryUrl>https://index.docker.io/v1/</registryUrl>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More detailed information can be found here: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#authenticating-with-private-registries

Comment: But isn't this for private registries, do I also need to do this for regular public hub?

Comment: U're welcome. So the term 'private registry' was fairly misleading.

Comment: Indeed, I thought it was a company private repo of images :)

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned work-around worked like magic. However, settings.xml file was missing on my machine. Created setttings.xml under /Users/username/.m2 directory on my machine as follows and it worked

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>docker.io</id>
            <username>your_username</username>
            <password>your_password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```